# Poltergeist #visit doesn't [always] load the page

Tags: poltergeist

I have an integration test that runs through a "confirm details" process, and then goes back to the main page to verify that the details have indeed been processed.

However, when I visit the main page near the end of the test, it doesn't go there...

```
within '#confirm_details' do
  page.find_button("Continue").trigger('click')
end

find("#email_confirmation_modal a.email_confirmation_yes").trigger('click')

expect(page).to have_css('span.balance') # Probably a false positive, but I've also
  # checked for elements that should only be there after the click

visit '/myaccount'
expect(page).to have_current_path '/myaccount'
```

... result:

```
Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_current_path('/myaccount')
  expected "/sign_up/confirm_details" to equal "/myaccount"
```

... but sometimes it's fine. Anyone have an idea why?

---

(I'll add other details here as I think of them.)

- The `my_account` action in the controller doesn't always get fired (this should surely be the app's entry point, right?)
- When it does work, the page loads in well under a second, so it's not running into the 2-second limit. In fact I've tried looping `visit '/myaccount' until page.current_path == '/myaccount'` and it hung.

Answer (score 0):

Page load is not guaranteed to have finished when `visit` returns (drivers try to do their best on that, but it's not always possible).  For that reason you should always use a Capybara provided matcher when there is one for what you're trying to test since they have waiting/retrying behavior built in.  In your case you should never use the RSpec provided `eq` matcher with current_path, instead you should be using the Capybara provided `have_current_path` matcher.

```
visit '/myaccount'
expect(page).to have_current_path('/myaccount')
```

If that doesn't fix your issue then it's likely to be something with your code that is filling in the "confirm details" so you'll probably want to add the tests full code to the question.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're seeing a version of the question that was only up for a few minutes and is now several hours old - I've already done that. I'm thinking you're probably right about the preceding code.

Comment: @PJSCopeland Then add the preceding code to the question - If I have to guess I'd say you have some sort of `click` directly before the `visit` where you're not actually waiting for whatever action the `click` triggers to finish.  However without actually seeing the code it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: I think there's probably too much happening in the test to post the rest of the code, but I'm pretty sure there is a click action immediately prior. I'll look into that once I'm back at work tomorrow.

Comment: @PJSCopeland Any update? Just a few lines previously may be enough if the test is too complicated.

Comment: I've played around with every permutation of "check for elements that the clicks should produce / remove" I can think of and haven't managed to make any progress. But I've added the relevant lines in case you see something I don't.

Comment: @PJSCopeland Oh - you're using `trigger` - all bets are off.  By doing that you're bypassing a number of checks for clickability, etc.  It's terrible practice when testing apps, I can't help you anymore.  You should be using `click_button`, 'click_link`, etc...

Comment: Yeah - I'm using it precisely _because_ the links are behind a modal popup and technically aren't clickable. I'm switching to Poltergeist from Selenium (which worked, but was a pain, and doesn't support the latest browsers) and trying to change as little as possible; and the error message specifically said to try that.

Comment: @PJSCopeland I have no idea where you got that info - Selenium runs the latest Chrome and Firefox (both in headless mode if wanted), while Poltergeist uses PhantomJS 2.1.1 which is basically equivalent to a 6-7 year old version of Safari (no ES6, no modern CSS, etc).  If the links aren't technically clickable then how would a user use the page.   There was a giant caveat in the error message - "If you don't care about ..." - if you're testing an app you should care about visibility and accessibility of elements. Using `trigger` makes sense for task automation, but does not for testing a page.

Comment: https://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2017/08/09/firefox-55-and-selenium-ide/ : "The bad news: from Firefox 55 onwards, Selenium IDE will no longer work." Second, a specific version of Selenium will only work with a specific version of Firefox, which is a massive pain to keep in sync. I didn't write the test, I'm just trying to maintain it.

Comment: @PJSCopeland Firstly, `Selenium IDE` is not the same as `Selenium` - it's a tool that used to be able to be used with `Selenium` -  Secondly, each release of selenium, and geckodriver / chromedriver, generally work with a 2-3 version range of Firefox/Chrome.  No ones forcing an upgrade every release, but even if you did it would be approximately every 2 months or so - not that much pain, and the benefit is you're actually testing your app on a browser your customers might actually be using, rather than hacking JS into tests on an ancient browser and basically making the tests worthless.

Comment: All right, fair enough. The amount of time I've wasted on this is irritating, but there it is. Is there a map of compatible `selenium-webdriver` and Firefox versions anywhere? Google's not helping me very much.

Comment: @PJSCopeland https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases lists the firefox versions each geckodriver supports, and then use the latest selenium-webdriver release